# sine(x) vs. sine(constant)

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry

This may be a beginner question, but I fear I need to ask it. Often when using graphing calculators online ([Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nqfu5lxaij)) you see $sin(x)$ which gives a sine wave.

Yet, if you do $sin(180/pi)$, for example, then you get a straight line. I know that this happens because of the obvious reason that the sine will be constant.

But when you have sine(x) that has a curving line, is that graphing all of the different values of $x$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The graph of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ consists of the points $(x,f(x))$ so $G_f=\{(x,f(x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, if the function is constant all the $y$-coordinates of these points are the same

Answer (score 1):

The calculator assigns to every arbitrary real number $x$ a value $f(x)$ and uses this to generate the graph of each corresponding ordinate $f(x)$ at each point on the $x$-line. It's the tips of all the ordinates that is the curve.

Thus when you input $f(x)$ in the utility, it assumes that you want the graph of the mapping $x\mapsto f(x)$ as described above. Now even if you input a constant, which of course $\sin(\text{whatever})$ is, where $\text{whatever}$ is some constant, it assumes you're plotting $x\mapsto \sin(\text{whatever}),$ which remains the same ordinate value $\sin(\text{whatever})$ at all values of $x.$